# How do you get the organizer badge?

Tags: support, badges, retagging

How do you get the organizer badge?
It says it's awarded for carrying out your "first retag" but I'm not exactly sure what that means.

Comment: Re-something means doing that something *again*. Retag means that you've changed the tags on a question.

Comment: I've treid that and it doesn't seem to grant me the badge.

Comment: How long ago did you do it?  Badges may be awarded once a day, so wait until tomorrow and see if you get your badge.

Comment: I will add that the organizer badge is awarded if you retag *somebody else's* question, not your own. See here: [Organizer badge not awarded after a retag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55546).

Comment: Also, you may have perhaps *suggested* an edit to retag another's question?  One cannot retag another user's question without approval from a reviewer, until one has earned 2K in rep.  Not all suggested edits are approved, and if not approved, a suggested retag is unsuccessful.

Comment: Do not retag old questions just for the sake of getting a badge. Gaming the system is frowned upon. There are plenty of recent posts that need attention.

Comment: Yes, [this suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1400956) would qualify for the Organizer badge, had it been approved. You (proposed to) change the tags on somebody else's question, so it qualifies, according to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/295232).